# POST JSON without specifying key using java

Tags: java, json, http-post

I have a URL given by the client and the client wants me to do HTTP POST to that URL with some JSON. But the issue is that he has not given me the key so that I can POST data like key=json string.

I asked him for it, but he insists that its possible. I was wondering how do I do it in java if at all it is possible.

EDIT:

Here is a simple way to send http post using Apache Http Client:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;


public class PostExample {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String url = "http://www.google.com";
        InputStream in = null;

        try {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            PostMethod method = new PostMethod(url);

            //Add any parameter if u want to send it with Post req.
            method.addParameter("p", "apple");

            int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);

            if (statusCode != -1) {
                in = method.getResponseBodyAsStream();
            }

            System.out.println(in);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Here we specify params using: method.addParameter("p", "apple");
So there is key "p" and value "apple". Now if there is no key and we just want to "push"(json) data, how we do it?
Pls I need **Java Specific** answer.

Comment: Why do you think you need a key? You just push the json as specified.

Comment: @bmargulies thats my question as to how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to use application/x-www-form-urlencoded, which would have key=value pairs. Don't.

Set the content type to application/json, and then just make the payload of the post *be the json*. There are no keys.

In java use commons-httpclient and perhaps CXF.